# How do you set selected option of Html.RadioButtonFor using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a radio button in MVC that is bound to a model. How do i set the selected option in jquery and have the UI display the changed Radio Button value?

Here is my html:

```
<label>Yes</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedPerson.is_selected, true, new { })
<label>No</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedPerson.is_selected, false, new { })
```

Here is my Jquery function i want to use to update the radio button.

```
function ToggleRadioButton() {
    //Set the Selected Value to 'True' or 'False'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#SelectedPerson_is_selected").prop("checked",false)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. When i implement the code you suggest, the UI does not reflect the updated Radio Button value. Is there a way to have the UI show the changed value?